# How do I fill in holes in svg text?

Tags: svg

I have a font that I'm using in SVG's that has hollow parts inside some letters:

[image: Letter F missing inner fill]

How do I fill in just that inner part to get something like this?

[image]

I feel like it should be something with fill-rule + a clip or mask maybe?

```html
<style>
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Bungee+Shade&display=swap');
</style>

<svg viewport="0 0 100 100">
 <rect ry="8" rx="8" id="svg_2" height="100" width="100" y="0" x="0" stroke-width="5" fill="#bfbfbf"/><text font-family="Bungee Shade" text-anchor="middle" x="50" y="78" font-size="100" fill="Red">F</text>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no simple way to do what you want.

The trouble is that the font glyph has been designed with a hole in it.  There is no CSS property that you can apply to the text that will fill in the hole.

You would need to convert the text to paths, then either:

- import the paths into a vector editor and draw the missing fill, or
- examine the paths definition and extract the section that corresponds to the "hole"

I suppose the other thing you could try is overlay the "Bungee Inline" font so that it lines up with the holes. You will likely have to fiddle with the font size and letterspacing. But it might work...

Answer (score 0):

With 0.1em of letter spacing and a left margin of 0.145em, the inline font seems to match up fairly well. But for best results, use the tool at [djr.com/bungee#tester](https://djr.com/bungee#tester), where you can generate SVGs quite easily. There's also a JQuery tool that you can use to style text automatically in web pages. It's made by the font's developer, so it ought to work perfectly.

Here's an SVG I made using their tool. It just needed a bit of editing to fit it into a square and add a background with rounded corners:

```html
<svg version='1.1' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' width='140' height='140' viewBox='6 39 140 140'>
<defs>
<path id='shade-notdef' d='M735 -159C749 -159 760 -155 766 -149L896 -41C905 -33 910 -22 910 -4V724C910 756 896 770 864 770H136C122 770 111 767 104 761L-25 652C-34 644 -39 633 -39 615V-113C-39 -145 -25 -159 7 -159ZM711 591V20H160V591Z' />
<path id='shade-46' d='M131 -119C145 -119 156 -115 162 -109L292 -1C301 7 306 18 306 36V114H341C355 114 366 118 372 124L502 232C511 240 516 251 516 269V389C516 421 502 435 471 435L583 528C592 536 597 547 597 565V684C597 716 583 730 551 730H105C91 730 80 727 73 721L-56 612C-65 604 -70 593 -70 575V-73C-70 -105 -56 -119 -24 -119Z' />
<path id='outline-notdef' d='M864 -30C882 -30 890 -22 890 -4V724C890 742 882 750 864 750H136C118 750 110 742 110 724V-4C110 -22 118 -30 136 -30ZM860 720V0H140V720Z' />
<path id='outline-46' d='M105 -10H260C292 -10 306 4 306 36V223H470C502 223 516 237 516 269V389C516 421 502 435 470 435H306V519H551C583 519 597 533 597 565V684C597 716 583 730 551 730H105C73 730 59 716 59 684V36C59 4 73 -10 105 -10Z' />
<path id='regular-notdef' d='M900 -4V724C900 749 889 760 864 760H136C111 760 100 749 100 724V-4C100 -29 111 -40 136 -40H864C889 -40 900 -29 900 -4ZM850 10H150V710H850Z' />
<path id='regular-46' d='M260 0C285 0 296 11 296 36V233H470C495 233 506 244 506 269V389C506 414 495 425 470 425H296V529H551C576 529 587 540 587 565V684C587 709 576 720 551 720H105C80 720 69 709 69 684V36C69 11 80 0 105 0Z' />
<path id='inline-notdef' d='M120 -20H880V740H120ZM870 -10H130V730H870Z' />
<path id='inline-46' d='M178 90H188V324H416V334H188V620H497V630H178Z' />
</defs>
<rect x='6' y='39' width='140' height='140' rx='10' ry='10' style='stroke:none;fill:#bfbfbf' />
<!-- Text: F (1 bytes) -->
<!-- F -->
<use transform='translate(37.76 150.08) scale(0.144 -0.144)' xlink:href='#shade-46' style='stroke:none;fill:#d74332' />
<!-- F -->
<use transform='translate(37.76 150.08) scale(0.144 -0.144)' xlink:href='#outline-46' style='stroke:none;fill:#d74332' />
<!-- F -->
<use transform='translate(37.76 150.08) scale(0.144 -0.144)' xlink:href='#regular-46' style='stroke:none;fill:#000000' />
<!-- F -->
<use transform='translate(37.76 150.08) scale(0.144 -0.144)' xlink:href='#inline-46' style='stroke:none;fill:#d74332' />
</svg>
```